# Forcing ints to initialize to 0 msvc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is there any compiler setting or other way to force an int to be initialized to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any compiler setting or other way to force an int to be initialized to 0?

Unfortunately, there is no way in the language and if the compiler offers such a setting it goes against the standard and therefore should not be used.

May I ask why you need this? Is explicit initialization not enough? Or would you like to be warned when uninitialized memory i used? The latter can be achieved using `valgrind`'s memory profiler.

Comment: Basically just for a catch all in case there were any bugs caused by uninitialized values. the memory profiler sounds like what I need, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Statics are always initialized to the default value (which for an `int` is 0). But you don't want them, do you?